# Censhare REST API throwing 401

Tags: java, rest

I have build a custom REST API and I get below response for the POST request when tested via postman:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /ws/rest/exercise/demoapi/createNewAssetJsonDemo. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone pls help get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to move forward by selecting *basic Authorization*. Pls check the below link for screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI1Db.png